# Embedding of this free algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a variety of algebra.  Prove $F(X)$, the free algebra in $V$ with basis $X$ can be embedded in $F(Y)$ if $X \subset Y$.

I found this question on Chegg [here](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/let-v-variety-algebras-let-f-x-denote-free-algebra-v-basis-x-prove-x-y-f-x-embedded-f-y--q21917467) while trying to study, but the answer is absolutely incorrect.  They literally state that since $X \subset Y$, then $F(X) \subset F(Y)$ so clearly it can be embedded.  I do think this is a really interesting question and something I should be able to show.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?  I know that $F(X)$ a free algebra means that $\forall A \in V, \forall \phi: X \rightarrow A,$ there exists a unique homomorphism $\bar{\phi}: F \rightarrow A$ that has the commutative diagram given by $X \rightarrow F$ (by $\iota), F \rightarrow A$ (by $\bar{\phi}$ and $X \rightarrow A ($ by $\phi)$.  Am I just looking for an injective homomorphism or is there something else I need to show about the mapping?

Comment: Do you know that $F$ is a functor?

Comment: @EricWofsey I have never seen that word before so no

Comment: @EricWofsey I am still looking for a way to do this.  Any hints you could provide me would be very appreciated

Comment: What's "way off" about thinking that $X\subset Y$ means subset? It can't be a subalgebra if it $Y$ is not an algebra itself...

Comment: @ArnaudD. sorry I really don't understand free algebras.  Do you have any hints on how to find such an embedding?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958984/how-do-i-prove-that-s-subset-t-implies-fs-is-monomorphic-to-ft) for a solution where $V$ is the variety of groups. The proof works in the same way for every variety.